# How to extract private key from pfx file using openssl?

Tags: openssl, private-key, pkcs#12

I was looking for this private key to add ssl certificate in Softlayer's "Add Certificate" wizard and to use it further with Local Load Balancer.

I googled and tried following openssl command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem
```

But I ended up with invalid "RSA PRIVATE KEY". Please help.

Answer (score 63):

Your command is correct, and gives you the **encrypted** private key in PKCS#8 format. If you need the **unencrypted** private key, just add the `-nodes` option:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out key.pem
```

If you need the private key in old RSA format, you should convert the given key with the `openssl pkcs8` command:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in key.pem -out rsakey.pem
```

See the documentation for details:

- https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-pkcs12.html
- https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-pkcs8.html

Answer (score -1):

Two things you can check in this issue,

1. Make sure to add -nodes property in the OpenSLL command you used, so the extracted RSA Private key will be an unencrypted. Example,

   ```
   pkcs12 -in certificate-name.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out private-key.pem
   ```
2. You can remove the bag and key attributes line from Private Key and try it.

Check out a good explanation to this issue on my blog at: [How To Extract Private Key From PFX Certificate File](https://karthikekblog.com/how-to-extract-private-key-from-pfx-certificate-file/)

Comment: If you are linking to your own web site, you need to be explicit about it. See also [How not to be a spammer.](/help/promotion)